# How to create BSP project in VxWorks 7?

Tags: vxworks, wind-river-workbench

In older version VxWorks there was an option to create BSP project (in Workbench) by selecting "Boot loader/ BSP project" in projects section, but in VxWorks 7 there is no such option available.

Can some one please tell me how to create BSP project in VxWorks 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VxWorks BootApp image is created using a VxWorks Kernel Image project and the 
PROFILE_BOOTAPP in the Workbench Development Environment as follows:

1. Right click the Project Explorer view and select New > Wind River Workbench
   Project.
2. Select Kernel image from the build type drop-down list. 
   Click Next to continue.
3. In the Project name field, enter a name for the project. 
   e.g. XXXX.

   Leave Create project in workspace selected and click Next to continue.
4. On the Project Setup screen, choose the following settings using the 
   drop-down lists:

   Based on      : a source build project 
   Project       : XXXXX 
   BSP           : YOUR BSP 
   Toolchain     : gnu

NOTE: The VxWorks BootApp requires a Uniprocessor (UP) source build project.

Leave the other Options set to the defaults.

Click Next.

5. Select the PROFILE_BOOTAPP from the Profile drop down list.
6. Click Finish to create the project.
7. Right-click the new project in the Project Explorer and select:

   Build > Set Active Build Spec > default_romCompress.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this project type is no longer available.

Instead, you can build a VxWorks Image Project and select the profile `BOOT_APP` to build your bootloader.